# How do I Format a JS Object for a D3 Dendrogram Chart in (Angular)JS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, d3.js

I am trying to extend an ElasticUI project with a D3 Dendrogram Chart.

Apolagia:
I know ElasticUI is depreciated because it's no longer maintained, but it has brought me a long way and let me experiment with elastic data in ways I, as a total beginner in both Javascript AND AngularJS could never have dreamt of had I jumped straight in and used only elasticsearch.js and tried to code a 'service' for it. Second thing: I say I have an Object, but it might be JSON data, an Array or a formatted String, for all I know. The browser console says my data contains "Objects".

Here's a slimmed down version of my html, with just the dendrogram.

```
<body eui-enabled="true" ng-app="moviesearch" ng-controller="IndexController" eui-index="indexName">
<div id="dendrogram" class="d3-chart">
    <eui-singleselect field="tweetMsg" size="10"></eui-singleselect>
    <div class="nav nav-list" eui-aggregation="ejs.TermsAggregation('entries').field('tweetMsg').size(20)" eui-filter="ejs.TermsFilter('tweetMsg', bucket.key)" eui-enabled="filter.enabled" eui-filter-self="true">

            <eui-var eui-key="dendroSelectorChartConfig" eui-value='                
            {
                "name": "Top Level",
                "children": (treeMap(aggResult.buckets))                    
            }
            '/>

            <div class="container well">
                <div d3-hierarchy="dendroSelectorChartConfig" depth="3"></div>
            </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And here is the function in my controller. It probably shouldn't be in my controller should it? I haven't been able to make it work any other way.

```
$scope.treeMap = function mainTreeMapDiagramData(data) {
var i;
for(i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
     console.log("{\"name\":" + "\"" + data[i].key + "\"},");
     //     return "{\"name\":" + "\"" + data[i].key + "\"},";
     }
};
```

You may laugh, but this actually logs the resulting Aggregation Terms correctly to the browser console:

```
app.js:87 {"name":"https"},{"name":"t.co"},{"name":"movie"},{"name":"rt"}, {"name":"the"},{"name":"film"},{"name":"a"},{"name":"to"},{"name":"in"},{"name":"of"},{"name":"and"},
```

etc...

However, if I comment out my console.log() and uncomment my "return"... D3 does not display anything. If I copy a list like the one above into my HTML directly, it works.

I haven't even begun to think about the next level – as in children of the children – I'd be happy just to get one level to work.

Thank you for reading!

EDIT: if it helps, the project is online here:
https://analytics.molch.at/dendrogram.html

Answer (score 0):

This worked:

```
$scope.treeMap = function mainTreeMapDiagramData(data) {

 var i;
 arr = [];
 for (var key in data){
     if (typeof data[key] !== 'function') {
          arr.push({ name: data[key].key });
     }
 }

 return arr;

 };
```

However. A single-level dendrogram isn't really much of a dendrogram. Now I have to figure out how to add a termsAggregation for each bucket in the previous termsAggregation.